# order a collection of momentjs dates by the current date with linq.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, linq.js

I want to sort in ascending order a collection of momentjs date objects.

The problem is that moment.date() returns the day of the month number.

How can I sort this by the real date? and still returning momentjs dates from the query?

```
var meetingsOrdered = Enumerable.from(meetings).orderBy("$.meetingDate.date()").toArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date()` returns the day of the month of the date.  Moment instances are directly comparable so you don't need to do much more.

```
var meetingsOrdered = Enumerable.from(meetings)
    .orderBy("$.meetingDate")
    .toArray();
```